# What will happened if we insert extremely big data into query parameter?

Tags: rest, http, webapi

What will happened if we insert a book (or another extremely big data) into query parameter in the GET request(for example)?
Probably it is unrealistic problem. But I had this question in an interview.

I only found that some servers can ignore such requests. But if they not. Maybe it can lead to some other troubles?

Comment: I would expect any well-configured server to return [a 414 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414).

Comment: Either the client (library) gives an error, or an intermediate proxy (if any) gives an error, or the web server returns an error, or the server-side application returns an error, or everything goes well, depending on the configuration and coding of all components in between.

Answer (score 0):

In general, **anything** could happen. In WebAPI in particular, there is a 16,000-character-limit, read more here:

https://support.airtable.com/docs/enforcement-of-url-length-limit-for-web-api-requests

Comment: That is just the limit of one particular server implementation.